# How to read JSON Array Value in windows phone?

Tags: php, windows-phone-7, json.net, arrays

I am encountering a problem when trying to read a JSON array object.

I am using PHP to create the JSON data.

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // looping through all results
    // products node
    $response["records"] = array();
    //$response["products"] = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
    {
        // temp user array
        $record = array();
        $record["vehicleNo"] = $row["vehicleNo"];
        $record["vehicleType"] = $row["vehicleType"];
        $record["inTime"] = $row["inTime"];
        $record["outTime"] = $row["outTime"];
        $record["entryUser"] = $row["entryUser"];

        // push single record into final response array
        array_push($response["records"], $record);
    }

    // success
    $response["success"] = 1;

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

The above code returns the following JSON:

```
{"records":[{"vehicleNo":"6545","vehicleType":"Bike","inTime":"2013-08-01 18:11:20","outTime":"2013-08-01 19:27:55","entryUser":"srini"}],"success":1}
```

I am using the following code to parse the JSON:

```
var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyBookList>(e.Result);

Console.WriteLine(rootObject.success);
MessageBox.Show(rootObject.success.ToString());
foreach (var re in rootObject.recordsss)//
{
    Debug.WriteLine(re.value_record);
    MessageBox.Show(re.value_record);
}

public class MyBookList
{
    public string success { get; set; }
    public MyRecords[] recordsss { get; set; }
}

public class MyRecords
{
    public string value_record { get; set; }
}
```

But it throws an "**Object reference not set to an instance of an object**" error.

How can I solve this problem and read the JSON data properly.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your classes don't match your JSON data.  They need to match, or Json.NET will not be able to populate the values, and they will remain null.  This is the most likely cause of the error you are seeing.

Try making your classes like this:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public int success { get; set; }
    public List<Record> records { get; set; }
}

public class Record
{
    public string vehicleNo { get; set; }
    public string vehicleType { get; set; }
    public string inTime { get; set; }
    public string outTime { get; set; }
    public string entryUser { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can deserialize it and read it like this:

```
var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(e.Result);

Console.WriteLine("success = " + rootObject.success);
foreach (var re in rootObject.records)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("vehicleNo = " + re.vehicleNo);
    Debug.WriteLine("vehicleType = " + re.vehicleType);
    Debug.WriteLine("inTime = " + re.inTime);
    Debug.WriteLine("outTime = " + re.outTime);
    Debug.WriteLine("entryUser = " + re.entryUser);
}
```